# Symmetry line of triangle at an angle

Tags: python, opencv

What is the best way do draw a symmetry line of a triangle (at an angle) in Python 3.X using OpenCV?

[image]

I used Harris Corner Detector to find the top of the triangle:

```
image = cv2.imread('triangle.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)
corners = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,5,0.04)
corners = cv2.dilate(corners,None)
image[corners>0.01*corners.max()]=[0,255,0]
```

Comment: what is the input? the image of the triangle or the three points? What have you tried?

Comment: Input is the triangle, I have tried find the furthest triangle top from centroid and connect these 2 points with line, but I failed

Comment: Get the 3 vertices. Identify the one to be the "top". Then for the other two, get the mid-point between them, i.e, center of the base. Then draw the line from the "top" point to the mid-point on the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same idea as stated in [fmw42's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617586/symmetry-line-of-triangle-at-an-angle-opencv#comment103544744_58617586), so here comes by version of this idea. My assumption is, that there's only a single (more or less perfect) [isosceles triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle) present in the image.

Following steps are done:

1. Find the extreme outer contours in the grayscale converted image, see [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) and [`RetrievalModes`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71).
2. Find the triangle vertices using [`cv2.minEnclosingTriangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1513e72f6bbdfc370563664f71e0542f).
3. (Optional) Refine the found vertices by finding the closest points in the original found contour. See following code example, why that maybe matters.
4. Calculate all edge lengths. The "top" vertex is the one with the least number of unique edge lengths.
5. Calculate the mid point on the base, and draw line from "top" vertex to that point.

Here comes the code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Some dummy image
img = cv2.fillPoly(img=np.zeros((500, 500, 3), np.uint8),
                   pts=np.array([[[200, 100], [400, 200], [300, 300]]]),
                   color=(0, 0, 255))

# Find only external contours in grayscale converted image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Find triangle vertices of minimum area enclosing contour
_, triangle = cv2.minEnclosingTriangle(contours[0])
pts = np.int32(np.squeeze(np.round(triangle)))
print('\nminEnclosingTriangle: \n', pts)

# Refine/improve triangle vertices (if wanted)
idx = [np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(contours[0] - pt, axis=2)) for pt in pts]
pts = np.int32(np.squeeze(contours[0][idx]))
print('\nRefined: \n', pts)

# Find index of "top" vertex by finding unique edge lengths; "top" has less than the two base vertices
idx = np.argmin([np.size(np.unique(np.linalg.norm(pts - pt, axis=1))) for pt in pts])
top = pts[idx]

# Find mid point of the base vertices
base = np.array([pts[i] for i in np.arange(3) if i != idx])
base_mid = np.int32(np.round(np.mean(base, axis=0)))

# Draw angle bisector line
img = cv2.line(img, tuple(top), tuple(base_mid) , (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And these are the outputs for my dummy example:

```
minEnclosingTriangle: 
 [[199  99]
 [300 300]
 [400 200]]

Refined: 
 [[200 100]
 [300 300]
 [400 200]]
```

[image: Output]

Please note, that some modifications might be needed for non-perfect isosceles triangles, e.g. instead of finding unique edge lenghts, one might need to set up a threshold, so that edge lenghts within some tolerance are also counted as similar. This can happen quite fast, especially if the contour detection isn't good due to - for example - interpolated pixels from JPG compression.

Anyway - hope that helps!

Disclaimer: Currently, I'm playing around with Python's list comprehension. So, I'm sorry, if there's some (inappropriate) overusage here.

Comment: Nice work. Lots of numpy methods here for me to learn. Thanks.